# Read column from csv with java spark

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

I try to read a csv with java and spark.

Now I do this:

```
    String master = "local[2]";
    String csvInput = "/home/username/Downloads/countrylist.csv";
    String csvOutput = "/home/username/Downloads/countrylist";

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(master, "loadwholecsv", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), System.getenv("JARS"));

    JavaRDD<String> csvData = sc.textFile(csvInput, 1);
    JavaRDD<List<String>> lines = csvData.map(new Function <String, List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public List<String> call(String s) {
            return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
        }
    });
```

So I have all the "lines" of the csv-file as a line in my RDD. I also wrote this method for getting a column:

```
public static JavaRDD<String> getColumn (JavaRDD<List<String>> data, final int index)
{
    return data.flatMap(
        new FlatMapFunction <List<String>, String>() 
        {
            public Iterable<String> call (List<String> s) 
            {
                return Arrays.asList(s.get(index));
            }
        }
    );
}
```

But later I want to do many transformations on columns and change position of columns etc. So it would be easier to have an RDD filled with the COLUMNS as Arraylists, not the LINES.

Has anyone an idea how to achieve this? I don't want to call "getColumn()" n-times.

Would be great if you can help me.

**Explanation:**
My csvData looks like this:

```
one, two, three
four, five, six
seven, eight, nine
```

My lines RDD looks like this:

```
[one, two, three]
[four, five, six]
[seven, eigth, nine]
```

**But** I want this:

```
[one, four, seven]
[two, five, eight]
[three, six, nine]
```

Comment: So what is the type of the expected RDD? `RDD<String[]>` ?

Comment: It's RDD<List<String>>

Comment: So it's what you have already.  What needs to change?

Comment: As i say, i want to have COLUMNS not LINES in my RDD<List<String>>

Comment: So given your original data is `"1, one, uno \ 2, two, dos \ 3, three, tres"`, and your current RDD is `["1", "one", "uno" \ "2", "two", "dos" \ "3", "three", "tres"]`, you would like an RDD: `["1","2","3" \ "one", "two", "three" \ "uno", "dos", "tres"]`, basically transposing the RDD?

Comment: @maasg: mostly like that, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

To do a map-reduce based matrix transposal, which is basically what is being asked, you would proceed by:

1. Transform your lines into indexed tuples: (hint: use zipWithIndex and map)

   > ```
   > [(1,1,one), (1,2,two), (1,3,three)]
   > [(2,1,four), (2,2,five), (2,3,six)]
   > [(3,1,seven), (3,2,eigth), (3,3,nine)]
   > ```
2. Add the column as key to each tuple: (hint: use map)

   > ```
   > [(1,(1,1,one)), (2,(1,2,two)), (3,(1,3,three))]
   > [(1,(2,1,four)), (2,(2,2,five)),(3,(2,3,six))]
   > [(1,(3,1,seven)), (2,(3,2,eigth)), (3,(3,3,nine))]
   > ```
3. Group by key

   > ```
   > [(1,[(3,1,seven), (1,1,one), (2,1,four)])]
   > [(2,[(1,2,two), (3,2,eigth), (2,2,five)])]
   > [(3,[,(2,3,six),(1,3,three), (3,3,nine))])]
   > ```
4. Sort values back in order and remove the indexing artifacts (hint: map)

   > ```
   > [ one, four, seven ]
   > [ two, five, eigth ]
   > [ three, six, nine ]
   > ```

Comment: How can i do this on the lists inside the RDD? By using zipWithIndex i would get a Tuple like (LIST, INDEX). I am a bit confused, how to get ([(element,index),(element,index)])

Comment: @progNewFag how would you transform `List(A, B, C)` into `List((A,1), (B,2),(C,3))`? Hint: plain Java, not Spark

Comment: I did the first two steps: http://pastie.org/private/u8zjkgkf6qakw96uk7dq . But i don't know how to do the grouping above the lists. Can you help me?

Comment: @progNewFag http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#groupByKey()

Comment: I am a bit confused, because i dont have an JavaPairRDD. Instead I have just a JavaRDD, how to group there?

Answer (score 0):

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("csvReader").master("local[2]").config("com.databricks.spark.csv","some-value").getOrCreate();  

String path ="C://Users//U6048715//Desktop//om.csv";    

Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> df =spark.read().csv(path);   
df.show();
```

Comment: output :
+-------------------+---+----+
|                _c0|_c1| _c2|
+-------------------+---+----+
|CCC:000455763800001|  1|  F1|
| WOS:00045576380002|  2|  F2|
| WOS:00045576380003|  3|null|
| WOS:00045576380004|  0|  F4|
| WOS:00045576380005|  9|  F5|
| WOS:00045576380006|  2|  s1|
| WOS:00045576380007|  4|  s2|
| WOS:00045576380008|  4|  s4|
| WOS:00045576380009|  1|  s5|
+-------------------+---+----+