# How to perform filter in javardd by header?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, filterfunction

I am working on a `JavaRDD` code where I have to upload a csv into a `JavaRDD` named `RestaurantDetailRDD`. The `RestaurantDetailRDD` has an address column which must be filtered into another `RDD` named `addressRDD`. I just need the filter condition where I can split the address column by header provided in the csv.

```java
// provide path to input text file
String path = "/home/lingesh/Downloads/newitems.csv";

// read text file to RDD
JavaRDD<String> restaurantDetailRDD = sc.textFile(path);

// collect RDD for printing
for(String line:restaurantDetailRDD.collect()){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

As you can see I just created the `RestaurantDetailRDD`

I expect the address column to be in placed in different `RDD`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898090/extract-only-certain-columns-in-java-spark

Comment: Have you tried anything? ALso, can you explain what you mean by "has an address column which must be filtered into another RDD"? Finally, can you provide some sample input and expected output?

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: another solution could transform the java rdd into a dataset and then take the column you want to use.

Comment: crawlingpage_address,crawlingpage_name,crawlingpage_ratings,crawlingpage_reviews
"411 Main Street, Pleasanton, CA, United States",1. Frontier Spice Indian Restaurant And Catering,5/5," (, - 7 reviews) "
"6167 Jarvis Ave, Newark, CA, USA",2. Oasis Palace Restaurant,4/5," (, - 1 review) "
"856 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA, United States",3. Chennai Kings,5/5," (, - 6 reviews) "
 /* This is the dataset which I want to place the crawling_page_address in a separate RDD*/

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of your `address` column, you just can do a `map` function to transform the RDD into another RDD.

```
JavaRDD<String> columnRdd = rdd.map(f -> {

    String[] arr = f.split(",");
    return arr[position];
});

System.out.println("new count " + columnRdd.count());
```

It's better in this way because you're using spark functions which means you can handle spark partitions and make the computation faster. Don't try to use basic java functions until you really need print results for testing.

Comment: Will try and let you know the results. Thanks for the valuable suggestion (y)